# Line graph - dividing the y-variable with 1000

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've created a line graph showing yearly funding using this code:

```
ggplot(yearly, aes(x=year, y=Total_US_received)) + ggtitle("Total Funding Received") + geom_line(color="darkblue") + labs(y="US$")
```

By doing this I get the following result:

[image]

I would like to divide the variable Total_US_received with 1000 to make the graph more easily read. This far I've tried by adding this to my code:

```
transform(yearly, Total_US_received1000=Total_US_received/1000)

ggplot(yearly, aes(x=year, y=Total_US_received1000)) + ggtitle("Total Funding Received") + geom_line(color="darkblue") + labs(y="US$")
```

but get following error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Total_US_received1000' not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my data:

```
yearly <- structure(list(year = 2006:2010, Total_US_received_from.CERF = c(65091455.5, 
204409211, 200351170.5, 180924822, 290493687.5), Total_US_required = c(828538873.5, 
2986369814, 1554939106, 2144420061, 7724926517), Total_US_received = c(215790327.5, 
1988581112, 1698825389, 1509823414, 4975642034)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You can pass `Total_US_received/1000` inside `aes`, you don't have to change your data. NB, don't forget to add thousands to y lab.

Comment: try: `ggplot(transform(yearly, Total_US_received1000=Total_US_received/1000), ...` or assign the `transform(yearly,..` to an object or as PoGibas suggested which is simplest.

Comment: If it's your intention to add a column to `yearly` you're not reassigning the output of tranform back to your dataframe.  e.g. try `yearly <- transform(yearly, Total_US_received1000=Total_US_received/1000)`

Comment: @krads is right. This works:  
`yearly <- structure(list(year = 2006:2010, Total_US_received_from.CERF = c(65091455.5, 204409211, 200351170.5, 180924822, 290493687.5), Total_US_required = c(828538873.5, 2986369814, 1554939106, 2144420061, 7724926517), Total_US_received = c(215790327.5, 1988581112, 1698825389, 1509823414, 4975642034)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
 
yearly <- transform(yearly, Total_US_received1000=Total_US_received/1000)
 

ggplot(yearly, aes(x=year, y=Total_US_received)) + ggtitle("Total Funding Received") + geom_line(color="darkblue") + labs(y="US$")`